# How do I change JavaDoc syntax color for Groovy

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, eclipse-plugin

I have my syntax highlighting set up pretty much exactly how I want it with one basic problem, I can't seem to figure out what is causing the coloring of the JavaDoc comments to be the color they are.

```
/**
* This is the sort of thing I'm looking to change the color of,
* note the two asterisks to kick it off.
* 
* args foo
* return bar
*/
```

So far I've gone to Preference > Groovy > Editor and looked there, there is no reference to either comments or JavaDoc comments.  So I followed a link over to Preferences > Java > Editor.  They do have the JavaDoc comments in there, but changing the color there has no effect.

Does anyone know where the correct place is to be changing that color?

Comment: Have you looked at colour scheme plugins for eclipse, or would this be specific to Groovy (I've not used Groovy so I'm a bit unsure)?

Comment: @hnelepls I'm using one, actually, put it doesn't seem to interact with groovy in a way I would expect.  The reason I put this under plugins is because the Groovy support is a plug in itself...

Comment: http://mydigitalbricks.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/changing-syntax-highlighting-for.html According to this you can change the colour scheme in the Groovy -> Editor section...

Comment: @hnelepls I did check there, but I didn't see anything to change the color of that particular syntax part.

Answer (score 1):

Okay this ended up being a little convoluted.  The colors are indeed affected by the Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring > Javadoc section.  But, owing to the unique way Eclipse preferences are made, those preferences will not affect the Javadocs unless you follow a fairly specific routine.

*note, this routine only applies to a very specific situation:  If you load up a syntax coloring by using [Color Theme](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/) and you don't like how the JavaDoc elements are colored in Groovy, but do like how they show up in Java.  It ought to be controlled by Java, but for some reason it's not, and clicking apply on the current Java color scheme doesn't do anything.

Basically, you need to change the color to something else, apply it, then change it back to the original color and apply it.  And apparently you have to do it while these elements are on a text page that you can see running in the background (Eclipse syntax colors changes are like sub atomic particles apparently.)  This will make it so that the Java syntax coloring is able to over-write whatever the Color Theme tool did to the Groovy preferences...

Anyway, yeah, it's a bit convoluted and is probably a bug.  But at least it can be worked around.